# Android, Kotlin DL (Deep Learning): проблема с TensorFlow

Tags: android

Всем привет.
Есть мой тестовый Android проект: https://github.com/invweb/KotlinDL
Я подключил kotlindl и получаю непонятную мне ошибку: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot find TensorFlow native library for OS: linux, architecture
Я пытался подключить TensorFlow

Grade:

```
implementation("org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.14.0")
```

Так же я подключаю:

Grade:

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlin-deeplearning-tensorflow:0.5.2")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlin-deeplearning-onnx:0.5.2")
```

безрезультатно

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: ru.mobile_solutions.kotlindl, PID: 27995
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot find TensorFlow native library
> for OS: linux, architecture: x86_64. See
> https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/java/README.md
> for possible solutions (such as building the library from source).
> Additional information on attempts to find the native library can be
> obtained by adding org.tensorflow.NativeLibrary.DEBUG=1 to the system
> properties of the JVM.
> at org.tensorflow.NativeLibrary.load(NativeLibrary.java:77)
> at org.tensorflow.TensorFlow.init(TensorFlow.java:67)
> at org.tensorflow.TensorFlow.(TensorFlow.java:82)
> at org.tensorflow.TensorFlow.init(TensorFlow.java:67)
> at org.tensorflow.Graph.(Graph.java:479)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlinx.dl.api.core.GraphTrainableModel.(GraphTrainableModel.kt:113)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlinx.dl.api.core.Sequential.(Sequential.kt:26)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlinx.dl.api.core.Sequential$Companion.of(Sequential.kt:45)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlinx.dl.api.core.Sequential$Companion.of$default(Sequential.kt:39)
> at
> ru.mobile_solutions.kotlindl.MainActivity.testKotlinDL(MainActivity.kt:40)
> at
> ru.mobile_solutions.kotlindl.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:36)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8305)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8284)
> at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1417)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3626)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

может быть есть у кого идеи: "что с этим делать"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

понял
kotlin DL - не для Android
))